# Походження слова дракула

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Існує багато легенд, історій та художніх творів з використанням персонажу Дракула - [вампір](http://sum.in.ua/s/vampir). Яке походження має слово "Дракула"?

[Брем Стокер — «Дракула»](https://www.bookclub.ua/ukr/read/stoker/Drakula_ukr/?recr_count2&utm_expid=10040872-80.c0M9SoUgSjC3A6vo8sUbHQ.2&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.ua%2F)

> — Граф Дракула?
>
> Старий чемно вклонився і відповів:
>
> — Так, я — Дракула; і дозвольте привітати вас, містере Харкер, у моєму
>   домі. Проходьте; нічне повітря прохолодне, а слід поїсти та відпочити.

В словниках даного слова не знайшла.

Comment: Якщо чесно, то невпевнений, що це про українську мову. Бо це власна назва.

Answer (score 2):

#### Word Origin and History for Dracula

**[Online Etymology Dictionary](//www.etymonline.com/word/Dracula), © 2010 Douglas Harper**

> 1. The vampire, from in Bram Stoker's novel (1897).
> 2. It was a surname of Prince Vlad II of Wallachia (d.1476), and means in Romanian "son of Dracul," literally "the dragon," from the name and emblem taken by Vlad's father, also named Vlad, c.1431 when he joined the Order of the Dragon, founded 1418 by Sigismund the Glorious of Hungary to defend the Christian religion from the Turks and crush heretics and schismatics.

**[English Wiktionary](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dracula#English), available under CC-BY-SA license**

Proper noun meaning:

> 1. The fictional vampire in the novel of the same name by Bram Stoker.
> 2. A former prince of Wallachia.

Origin:

> From the name Vlad III Dracula (also known as Vlad Țepeș), from his father's name Vlad II Dracul, who was given the name Dracul by the Order of the Dragon. Dracul comes from the Romanian drac (“devil”), itself deriving from the Latin draco (“dragon”).

Comment: We prefer answers in the language of a question (i.e.: for a question in English — answers in English, for a question in Ukrainian — answers in Ukrainian). However, if answering in another language is the only reasonable option for an answer's author, we appreciate such contributions as well (i.e. it's better to write a good answer in unexpected language than to write a bad answer in the expected language or than not to write any answer at all). Thanks for your contribution (I've added some bits of formatting if you do not mind).

Comment: Зніму мінус як продублюєте відповідь українською.